# Difference between memcpy_htod and to_gpu in Pycuda?

Tags: numpy, cuda, gpu, pycuda

I am learning PyCUDA, and while going through the documentation on pycuda.gpuarray, I am puzzled by the difference between pycuda.driver.memcpy_htod (also _dtoh) and pycuda.gpuarray.to_gpu (also get) functions. According to gpuarray [documentation](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html), .get().

For example,transfer the contents of self into array or a newly allocated numpy.ndarray. If array is given, it must have the right size (not necessarily shape) and dtype. If it is not given, a pagelocked specifies whether the new array is allocated page-locked.

Is this saying that .get() is implemented exactly the same way as pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtoh? Somehow, I think I am mis-interpreting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray.get()](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html#pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray.get) stores the GPUArray as a [numpy.ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray).

[pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtoh()](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtoh) and friends copy plain buffers between CPU and GPU memory without any processing of the data in the buffers.